# Nouns employed as nouns and adjectives

Tags: adjectifs, noms

> Je me moque de l’héroïne que je trouve mièvre et geignarde

It looks like French speakers are able to employ geignard (which has the form of a noun) as an adjective. (The WordReference.com dictionary lists it as serving as both noun and adjective.)

To what extent is French open to the practice of employing nouns as adjectives? What limits apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

The use of nouns as attibutive adjectives ("épithètes") is a trend that is growing in importance in a small area of vocabulary building. There seems to be to a certain extent enough freedom in coining terms along the lines accepted in this area;  certain relations have to be respected between the two words.

This site, [Pluriel des noms adjectivés](https://andreracicot.ca/plurielnomsadjectives/), provides a few instances, as wwell as the rule of formation of the plurals.

However, personally, I'd rather consider such constructions as constituting compound words: the concept of  gradability and  comparison are irrelevant.

*relation for "X Y"*: an X that is also a Y ("un X qui est aussi un Y")

- ballon sonde, ville dortoir, prêtre ouvrier, maison mère, carte mère, Dupont père, homme-serpent, poisson-chat, oiseau mouche, professeur femme, médecin femme,

*there are other relations*

- liaison satellite (link by means of  satellites), train grande vitesse (train à grande vitesse),

*beginning of a truly adjectival use*

- clochard (rare, p. métaph.) — des cités plus clochardes les unes que les autres,

2. 

In the domain of both attributive and predicative adjectives, only certain nouns, rather rare, can be used as adjectives; they are shown in dictionaries.

*some -ard ending nouns*

- (primarily a noun) veinard
- (adj and noun) geignard, bâtard, béquillard, binoclard, cabochard, poissard, etc.

*some -eur ending nouns (either primarily adj or primarily noun)*

- voleur, menteur, travailleur, flâneur, railleur, moqueur, rieur, raseur, (change of meaning), hâbleur,  <s>rateur</s> (noun), râleur, tueur, directeur, penseur,

There are all sorts of nouns of impredictable nature that can be used as true adjectives, although not fully.

- chien (change of meaning),  <s>chat</s>, cochon  (change of meaning), mouton  (change of meaning), chameau (change of meaning), vache  (change of meaning), oie (restricted use), fille (rare, Colette), croyant, mutant, sadique, émérite (primarily adj.), glouton (primarily adj.), traitre,

For instance "chien" is not used attributively, but can be used in comparisons ("il est encore plus chien"). On the contrary "cochon" (dirty) is used attributively ("un filme cochon", "un roman cochon"), but also predicatively ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Biribi_Discipline_militaire/PrmhEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22trop+cochon%22&pg=PT161&printsec=frontcover)). Usage must be learned one way or another; checking in dictionaries is not sufficient, at least for the time being, but will help: for instance, you can check "chien" in the TLFi, and you will find only examples of predicative use, but not the grammatical label "only in predicative use"; it is clearly not sufficient for acquiring effective knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. I’m going to look out for the examples that you’ve cited. It seems to me that the use of nouns as adjectives can usefully enhance the expressive possibilities of a language.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle « Attributively » en anglais devient « en tant qu'épithète » en français.

Comment: D'accord. Seulement le régionalisme alors : _un coup vraiment chien_...

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Eh bien, on peut peut-être prendre soin de ça dans une stipulation telle que « seulement attributif sauf régionalisme », ou plus précis, telle que « seulement attributif sauf Québec », ou même autrement, comme par exemple à la section où le régionalisme est mentionné, avec une stipulation telle que « attributif et en épithète ». Ça ne devrait pas être un problème.

Comment: _...not generally_ suffirait. C'est pas trop important, la précision peut rester en commentaire.

Comment: Another -eur instance: bagarreur. WordReference.com has it as noun and adjective but, from the suffix, I'd guess that use as a noun came first

Comment: @justerman Although both the TLFi and the Wiktionnaire mention the word as first an adj., which must be due to a higher frequency of use of the adj., the first recorded usage (see [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bagarreur) and [Pédale, col 3](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k32124522/f6.item)) is that of the noun, and it should be a noun  since the suffix -eur is a noun forming suffix (as you justly mention). By the way, do not get the impression that my answer treats this question in depth to any degree; there is much more to be said. Besides the fact that there are other (1/2)

Comment: @justerman  suffixes to examine I didn't go through the list of -ard and -eur ending nouns systematically; there is bound to be many more words and interesting facts. For the suffix -iste (after a quick perusal it seems there are not too many cases) there is for instance "physionomiste".  (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

The suffix *-ard* can be found in substantives (e.g. *clochard*) or words that can be both substantives and adjectives (e.g. *savoyard*.) See *[-ard](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ard)*. *Geignarde* belongs to the second group. *Geignard* was even only listed as an adjective in its [first appearance](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8G0260) in a dictionary.

Generally, any adjective can be used as a noun but it is more rare for nouns to be used as adjectives. You certainly cannot take a substantive at random and assume that it can easily be used as an adjective.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm surprised that geignard's use as adjective predated its use as noun.

Comment: Before being attested in a dictionary, *Geignard* was already known as a patronym. Many patronyms started as niknames based on a characteristic and were often expressed by an adjective. Geignard likely comes from *geigner*, a regional variant of *geindre* found in several Langue d'oïl dialects.

Comment: @justerman French is very comfortable using adjectives as nouns in cases where we wouldn't in English. We say 'the poor', 'the elderly', but French can also say 'a poor', 'an elderly', 'some poors', 'some elderlies', etc.!

Comment: @ Luke Sawczak: Thanks. I'll look out for them

Comment: @Luke Sawczak: Hardly a day has passed and I've spotted one in the wild: Le jeune m’a logé chez lui le temps que ma blessure guérisse